# SQL Server INNER JOIN with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables that I want to join. The first table is named `WorkItem`:

[image]

The second table is `WorkItem_Schedule`:

[image]

I want to get the **1st** joined row with `ActualEndDate IS NULL`.

In case of WorkItemId 3, I only want to join it on WorkItemScheduleId 95. Only the first row!

I tried this SQL statement, but I am having trouble:

```
  SELECT 
      W.WorkItemId
      ,MIN(WS.WorkItemScheduleId) test
      ,W.WorkItemName
      ,WS.[PhaseName]
      ,WS.[StartDate]
      ,WS.[EndDate]
      ,WS.[ActualStartDate]
      ,WS.[ActualEndDate]
  FROM 
      WorkItem W
  INNER JOIN 
      WorkItem_Schedule WS ON W.WorkItemId = WS.WorkItemId
  WHERE 
      WS.ActualEndDate IS NULL
  GROUP BY 
      W.WorkItemId;
```

I get an error

> Column 'WorkItem.WorkItemName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I google this error and found out that I need to add other columns in the select list to group by, so I tried this sql, but it return all schedules and not distinct workitemid:

```
SELECT 
   W.WorkItemId
  ,MIN(WS.WorkItemScheduleId) test
  ,W.WorkItemName
  ,WS.[PhaseName]
  ,WS.[StartDate]
  ,WS.[EndDate]
  ,WS.[ActualStartDate]
  ,WS.[ActualEndDate]
FROM 
    WorkItem W
INNER JOIN 
    WorkItem_Schedule WS ON W.WorkItemId = WS.WorkItemId
WHERE 
    WS.ActualEndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    W.WorkItemId, WS.PhaseName, WS.StartDate, WS.EndDate, WS.ActualStartDate, WS.ActualEndDate;
```

Please help! THanks in advance!

Comment: W.WorkItemId : W.WorkItemName are considered as 1:N by default, hence if you group by id, you may have multiple names for it. Something like min(W.WorkItemName) should solve the problem, I suppose.

Comment: Have a look at the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag

Comment: What is the logic behind joining to row 95?  All the rows have ActualEndDate NULL.   First joined row, ordered by what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cross apply` is probably the easiest way to do this:

```
select w.*, ws.*
from WorkItem w cross apply
     (select top 1 ws.*
      from WorkItem_Schedule ws
      where ws.WorkItemId = w.WorkItemId and
            ws.ActualEndDate is null
      order by ws.WorkItemScheduleId
     ) ws;
```

By "first", I assume you mean the one with the smallest `WorkItemScheduleId`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to get the "first" joined row.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
   W.WorkItemId
  ,WS.WorkItemScheduleId
  ,CASE WHEN WS.ActualEndDate IS NULL 
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY W.WorkItemId ORDER BY WorkItemScheduleId)  --ROW_NUMBER() only invoked when the ActualEndDate IS NULL 
        ELSE -1 END AS ROWN
  ,W.WorkItemName
  ,WS.[PhaseName]
  ,WS.[StartDate]
  ,WS.[EndDate]
  ,WS.[ActualStartDate]
  ,WS.[ActualEndDate]
  FROM WorkItem W
INNER JOIN WorkItem_Schedule WS
ON W.WorkItemId = WS.WorkItemId    
GROUP BY W.WorkItemId, WS.PhaseName, WS.StartDate, WS.EndDate, WS.ActualStartDate, WS.ActualEndDate) A
WHERE ROWN = 1 --Getting the "first" instance
```

Comment: best way or not, this is how I would do it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
W.WorkItemId
,W.WorkItemName
,WS.[PhaseName]
,WS.[StartDate]
,WS.[EndDate]
,WS.[ActualStartDate]
,WS.[ActualEndDate]
FROM WorkItem W
JOIN WorkItem_Schedule WS
 ON W.WorkItemId = WS.WorkItemId
WHERE WS.ActualEndDate IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 'PREVIOUS'
   FROM WorkItem_Schedule WS2
   WHERE W2.WorkItemId = WS.WorkItemId
   AND WS2.StartDate < WS.StartDate
   AND WS2.ActualEndDate IS NULL
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Joining on a particular row of a spectrum of values is relatively easy and involves no fancy tricks. First, a simple join will show you all of the candidate rows. As you see, you had 80% of the query done:

```
SELECT
    W.WorkItemId
    ,WS.WorkItemScheduleId
    ,W.WorkItemName
    ,WS.[PhaseName]
    ,WS.[StartDate]
    ,WS.[EndDate]
    ,WS.[ActualStartDate]
    ,WS.[ActualEndDate]
FROM 
    WorkItem W
INNER JOIN 
    WorkItem_Schedule WS 
 ON W.WorkItemId = WS.WorkItemId
WHERE 
    WS.ActualEndDate IS NULL
```

This gives you the row you want and others as well. Now just filter out the ones you don't want. The one you want has the smallest (earliest) date. Fine. Select that date:

```
...
WHERE 
    WS.ActualEndDate IS NULL
and WS.StartDate =(
    select  Min( StartDate )
    from    WorkItem_Schedule
    where   WorkItemId = W.WorkItemId
       and  ActualEndDate is NULL );
```

Don't let the subquery throw you. If your table is properly indexed, it will find your row using only index seeks.